# What is the logic behind shorter work hours during the summer?

Tags: employer-relations, work-time

The company I'm currently working for allows employees to leave the office early in the summer (around 2:30/3pm, West Coast USA, Pacific Time) if they've completed all their work for the day.  They call it summer hours.  As far as I know, the company does it to benefit the employees and allow them to enjoy the summer, and it does encourage people to be efficient with their time.  I'm not by any means complaining (I'd much rather work a 6 hour day than an 8 hour one), but the whole idea of being able to work less in the summer seems strange to me.  Why should the work take less time in the summer than it does the rest of the year?  Conversely, if we can operate just fine by leaving at 2:30 during the summer, why require people to stay until the standard closing time the rest of the year?  Does international business stall over the summer and require less work from people overall?  What's the logic behind this kind of practice?

Comment: Never heard about "summer hours". Mind including your location?

Comment: If you want to know the logic behind that, perhaps it's best if you ask *them* (your company). Only they know the logic behind their choices.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Western USA, Pacific Time.

Comment: @CMB You kind of answered your own question. It seems to be so that people can enjoy the summer, simple as that. When there is enough motivation to do so (e.g. to enjoy the nice sunny weather outside in the afternoon, when it's maybe too hot to work anyway), people might be able to put in some extra effort. But that doesn't necessarily mean that everyone is capable of operating at peak efficiency all year round..

Answer (score 4):

Different companies have different reasons.  Among them

- Lots of people (formally and informally) take off the last few hours on Friday anyway.  Once a critical mass of people are leaving early on Friday, the ability for other people to get work done tends to suffer (i.e. I need Bob to do x, Bob's not going to do x until Monday).  It can also create issues for other employees when they see a quarter of the office gone while they're still working or when some managers are stricter about hours on those days than others.  At that point, it's a lot less frustrating to just send everyone home early.
- Setting a time also tends to act as an anchor to encourage people that were leaving early to stay until the Friday end time rather than having people start to leave at lunch.  Better to have (most) everyone there until 2:30 than to have people start disappearing right after lunch.
- If you're doing a lot of work with European partners, the pace of work tends to slow in summer because that's when everyone wants to take their vacation time.  It's common to say that a European country "shuts down in August" even though that's an exaggeration.  But it is fair to say that lots of employees take a nice long vacation in August and the pace of work is noticeably slower.

Comment: I work for a company located in Spain that has "summer hours", but we do some extra time each day the rest of the year to compensate.  Also we have early leave on fridays the whole year. Summertime 6:45 hours rest of the year 8:30 hours fridays 6:30 hours